# Parse using Jackson Parser

Tags: android, json, jackson

I have just started to working with Jackson Library and I don't know how to parse my data. Can anyone help please?

Here is my json response...

```
{"flag":"1",
"data":[{"categoty_id":"150","category_name":"Baby &Kids"},{"categoty_id":"151","category_name":"Books & Comics"},{"categoty_id":"152","category_name":"Collectibles & Antiques"},{"categoty_id":"153","category_name":"Electronics"} ...and so on
```

To parse data I am using following

```
 try {
                            ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            parameters.add(new NameValuePair("store_id", "1"));

                            Log.e("Cat", "start querying...");
                            final String response = GetResponse.execPostScript("category.php?store_id=1");
                            Log.e("Cat",response);

                            JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
                            JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(response);
                            allCategory = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonParser, AllCategory.class);



                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            pD.dismiss();

                        }
```

My ProJo class is life follow

```
package com.elsner.bean;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "flag",
        "data"
})
public class AllCategory {

    @JsonProperty("flag")
    private String flag;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<Category> data = new ArrayList<Category>();
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public AllCategory() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param flag
     * @param data
     */
    public AllCategory(String flag, List<Category> data) {
        this.flag = flag;
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The flag
     */
    @JsonProperty("flag")
    public String getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param flag
     * The flag
     */
    @JsonProperty("flag")
    public void setFlag(String flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The data
     */
    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<Category> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param data
     * The data
     */
    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(List<Category> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

I am getting following run time error........

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.elsner.bean.AllCategory out of START_ARRAY token

But I am getting error in parsing my data.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: i am getting compile time error @ this code AllCategory allCategory = new ObjectMapper().readValues(jsonParser,AllCategory.class);.......... thanx for quick replay

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: ok i got it....i used readValues() instead of readValue()....thank you all

Comment: Ok i have solved this....it was my mistake....i have putted code inside loop...that should not be...see my edited question...it is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectMapper` class doesn't have `readValues()` method use `readValue()` instead.

Use This:

```
 AllCategory[] allCategory = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonParser,AllCategory[].class);
```

Comment: this works but now i am getting run time error.....com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.elsner.bean.AllCategory out of START_ARRAY token

Comment: i have changed my question...and i ll accept your answer as soon as i solved my problem

Comment: What is content after "at" word?

Comment: Your json contains an array, but you trying to parse it as object. This error occurs because object must start from `{`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97264/discussion-between-amy-and-hetal-upadhyay).